# How to query from an array for a single field in mongodb JAVA DRIVER.

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

Hello I have a collection called Movies with the following structure

Movies{
    Title, 
    Id,
    Characters[ {Character_name , actor_id} ]
    }

I am trying to query for a specific Character_name using a corresponding `actor_id` and id (movie). How is this possible without getting the whole list of movie characters? 
For example I want every `Character_name` *Brad Pitt* has played per each movie , in the form of an ArrayList.

Here is my code for creating an ArrayList of titles from Movies, how can I change this to obtain individual character names?

```
public static ArrayList popTitle() {

    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(
            "localhost", 27017));
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("Characters.actor_id", "162684857");
    DBCollection myCollection = db.getCollection("Movies");
    DBCursor cursor = myCollection.find(query);
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject theObj = cursor.next();


        BasicDBObject title = (BasicDBObject) theObj;
        String t = title.getString("title");
        myList.add(t);

    }



    Set<String> s = new LinkedHashSet<>(myList);
    myList.clear();
    myList.addAll(s);

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(myList.get(i));
    }

    return myList;
}
```

Here is what I have so far. The query results are null.

```
public static void popCharacter() {


    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(
            "localhost", 27017));
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    DBCollection myCollection = db.getCollection("Movies");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();


    query.put("id", "10015");
    query.put("Characters.actor_id", "162684857");



    DBCursor cursor = myCollection.find(query); 

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject theObj = cursor.next();

        BasicDBObject title = (BasicDBObject) theObj;
        String t = title.getString("Characters.Character_name");
        System.out.println(t);

    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks BatScream. I have modified the question. My query results are null.

Comment: You would need to add a project statement in your query, `characters.$:1`, which would project only the matching array item and not the entire character array.

Comment: Where should I place that statement in my code?

Comment: Thank you Blakes Seven but I am having trouble solving this using java.

Comment: Would you be able to help explain how I could translate JohnnHK's answer into java from the page you recommended?   @BlakesSeven

Comment: That may be the "accepted" answer, but there are many more answers on the question. So it's basic "dot notation" to match the element ( as used ) and the positional `$`  operator `"characters.$"` for the matched element in projection ( just like the answers say ). Then your result is a single array element, from which you reference the propery for the `"name"`.

Comment: I still do not understand how to perform the actual query in Java. @BlakesSeven